# Моделирование комнаты, нужно сдать в среду

Tags: python, turtle

[[image: пример]]Нужно создать программу, которая спрашивает у пользователя длину и ширину стены, а также цветовую палитру, которую будет использоваться для того, что раскрасить стену. Стену нужно раскрасить случайными цветами из цветовой палитры (цвета берутся из файла) и случайно выбранными фигурами. Хотела использовать черепаху, но она заходит за границы. В идеале это надо сделать 4 раза и потом смоделировать комнату.
Должно получится примерно так, но оно должно рисовать только в границах прямоугольника.

```
from turtle import *
from turtle import Screen
from random import randint
import random
seinalaius=float(input("Введите длину стены (500-1500): "))
seinapikkus=float(input("Введите ширину стены (500-900): "))
värvipalett=input("Какую цветовую палитру вы хотите использовать? (Valik: mustvalge(чёрно-белый), roosa(розовый), punane(красный), lilla(фиолетовый), sinine(синий), kollane(жёлтый), roheline(зелёный), beež(бежевый), oranž(оранжевый)): ")
fail=open(värvipalett + '.txt', encoding='UTF-8')
värvid=[]
for rida in fail:
    rida=rida.strip()
    värvid.append(rida)
up()
right(150)
forward(900)
down()
left(150)
for i in range(2):
    forward(seinalaius)
    left(90)
    forward(seinapikkus)
    left(90)
import math
up()
left(30)
a = math.sqrt((seinalaius**2) + (seinapikkus**2))
forward(a/2)
down()
while True:
    pöörded=randint(4,8)
    begin_fill()
    color(random.choice(värvid))
    for i in range(pöörded):
        pikkus=randint(0,150)
        forward(pikkus)
        lr=randint(1,2)
        if lr==1:
            left(90)
        else:
            right(90)
    end_fill()
    up()
    down()
```

Пример файла с синим цветом:

```
aliceblue
aquamanne
aquamarine1
aquamarine2
aquamarine3
aquamarine4
blue
blue1
blue2
blue3
blue4
CadetBlue
CadetBlue1
CadetBlue2
CadetBlue3
CadetBlue4
CornflowerBlue
cyan
cyan1
cyan2
cyan3
cyan4
DarkBlue
DarkCyan
DarkSlateBlue
DarkSlateGray
DarkSlateGray
DarkSlateGray2
DarkSlateGray3
DarkSlateGray4
DarkSlateGrey
DarkTurquoise
DeepSkyBlue
DeepSkyBlue2
DeepSkyBlue3
DeepSkyBlue4
DodgerBlue
DodgerBlue1
DodgerBlue2
DodgerBlue3
DodgerBlue4
LightBlue
LightBlue1
LightBlue2
LightBlue3
LightBlue4
LightSeaGreen
LightSkyBlue
LightSkyBlue1
LightSkyBlue2
LightSkyBlue3
LightSkyBlue4
LightSlateGray
LightSlateGrey
LightSteelBlue
LightSteelBlue1
LightSteelBlue2
LightSteelBlue3
LightSteelBlue4
MediumAquamarine
MediumBlue
MediumSlateBlue
MediumTurquoise
midnightblue
MidnightBlue
navy
NavyBlue
PaleTurquoise
PaleTurquoise1
PaleTurquoise2
PaleTurquoise3
PaleTurquoise4
PaleVioletRed
PowderBlue
RoyalBlue
RoyalBlue1
RoyalBlue2
RoyalBlue3
RoyalBlue4
SkyBlue
SkyBlue1
SkyBlue2
SkyBlue3
SkyBlue4
SlateGray
SlateGray1
SlateGray2
SlateGray3
SlateGray4
SteelBlue
SteelBlue1
SteelBlue2
SteelBlue3
SteelBlue4
turquoise
turquoise1
turquoise2
turquoise3
turquoise4
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint
import random

seinalaius = float(input("Введите длину стены (500-1500): "))
seinapikkus = float(input("Введите ширину стены (500-900): "))
värvipalett = input("Какую цветовую палитру вы хотите использовать? (Valik: mustvalge(чёрно-белый), roosa(розовый), punane(красный), lilla(фиолетовый), sinine(синий), kollane(жёлтый), roheline(зелёный), beež(бежевый), oranž(оранжевый)): ")
fail = open(värvipalett + '.txt', encoding='UTF-8')
värvid = []
for rida in fail:
    rida = rida.strip()
    värvid.append(rida)

up()
goto(-seinalaius / 2, -seinapikkus / 2)
down()

for i in range(2):
    forward(seinalaius)
    left(90)
    forward(seinapikkus)
    left(90)

up()
goto(0, 0)
down()

while True:
    pöörded = randint(4, 8)
    begin_fill()
    color(random.choice(värvid))
    for i in range(pöörded):
        pikkus = randint(0, 150)

        up()
        forward(pikkus)
        if not -seinalaius / 2 <= xcor() <= seinalaius / 2 or not -seinapikkus / 2 <= ycor() <= seinapikkus / 2:
            backward(pikkus)
        backward(pikkus)
        down()

        forward(pikkus)
        lr = randint(1, 2)
        if lr == 1:
            left(90)
        else:
            right(90)
    end_fill()
    up()
    down()
```

результат
[image: result]

и ещё на цвет aquamanne выдавалась ошибка и после удаления из файла проверял в течении 10 минут рисовалось пока не надоело.